# Organizing Rails files within app folder for api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, project-structure, class-names

All setups I've found use the following folder structure

```
/app
 /controllers
   /api
    /v1
 /views
   /api
    /v1
 /models
```

This is ok, I guess. But I am trying to get a structure that looks like

```
 /app
  /api
   /v1
    /controllers
    /views
   /v2
    /controllers
    /views
  /controllers #for non api stuff
  /views #for non api stuff
```

at the moment, my routes for the api are set as

```
scope module: :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    namespace :v1 do
    ..
  end
end
```

with controllers like `Api::V1::MyController < ApplicationController`

Is there a way to have this kind of structure?

Answer (score 0):

I think better way is to extract your api to gem.